# How to monitor root directory with glib/gio?

Tags: c, glib, gio

I'm trying to do a file monitor on the root file system directory. I use `g_file_new_for_path()` with `/` as the path and create the monitor with `g_file_monitor()`. But at execution no events are reported. If I use the path `//` events are thrown.

Is is a bug with GIO or do I need to use `//`?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of `g_file_new_for_path`:

```
path : A string containing a relative or absolute path. 
       The string must be encoded in the glib filename encoding
```

GLib file encoding iirc goes like this:
`[protocol:]//path/to/file`

I think this should work too:
`file:/` which is an alias to `//`